# how to replace the gray puzzle-piece with red stopsign on WebExtension on InstallTrigger.install call

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, installation, user-experience, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have a Firefox WebExtension. It's duly signed by addons.mozilla.org and generally working correctly.  But the user experience of installing it isn't very good.

I'm installing it from my own web site using the InstallTrigger.install() sequence [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_Extensions_and_Themes_From_Web_Pages) by Mozilla.

But this sequence seems to ignore the IconURL parameter. Instead my user gets a fairly scary popup box like this.

[image]

Is there any way to put my own icon on that box instead? Is there any way to simplify the installation sequence?

My code is pretty much cut and past from the mozilla docs.  Here it is.

HTML button

```
          <button id="extension-button-1" type="button" 
            class="btn btn-default btn-primary"
            onclick="return EgetExtension(event);"
            data-xpi="/install/browserextension/extension.xpi"
            data-iconurl="/install/browserextension/icon32.png"
            data-hash="sha256:aacf102b0cc6c9ffe370redacteddd1a8cac05cd4b2e9redactedd31394fb1a0"> Cobrowse </button>
```

Javascript

```
    var params = {
        "Extennsion": {
            URL: event.target.getAttribute('data-xpi'),
            IconURL: event.target.getAttribute('data-iconurl'),
            Hash: event.target.getAttribute('data-hash'),
            toString: function () { return this.URL; }
        }
    };
    InstallTrigger.install(params);
```

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Cobrowse",
  "short_name": "C3PO",
  "version": "3.7.1.17",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "author": "Example.",
  "description": "example. ",
  "homepage_url": "http://ww2.glance.net/products/panorama/co-browse/",
  "icons": {"128": "g128.png"},
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true },
  "permissions": [
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],
  ... etc
}
```

Comment: Please provide the *manifest.json* (or at least the relevant portions) and the code you are using to initiate the install. Basically, a MCVE. While it looks like this may be possible, giving an answer would require testing. It is *much* easier to test if we don't have to create the code from scratch.

Comment: You would almost certainly need to supply the icon in some way not through your *manifest.json*. Expecting it to pull the icon from the *manifest.json* would require the extension to actually be downloaded and extracted. This popup *should* be written to be displayed prior to the extension being downloaded. I have not checked the code to see that that is the case, but that would be the more secure method of writing it. The Firefox code does appear to support supplying an icon.

Comment: I have added some code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you desire is not possible.  The [Firefox source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-addons.js#57) ([2](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/base/content/browser-addons.js#281)) does not provide a way for you to specify this icon. It would be possible to change this if you had an extension or theme already installed which did so, but that is a bit counter to what you desire.

The icon is assigned by CSS based on the `popupid`. This is done in `chrome://browser/skin/browser.css` at line 3749 (on Firefox 53.0). The `popupid` is assigned based on the reason that the notification is being shown.  In this case that is `addon-install-blocked`.

Comment: Thanks for looking this up.  What is the purpose of the IconURL item in the parameter to `install()`?

Comment: @O.Jones, I did not look, yet, far enough to actually determine where it is used. I started looking from both directions, but stopped once I determined that there is nothing that can be done to affect that icon. The interface is defined [here](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/webidl/InstallTrigger.webidl#20), with the `InstallTriggerData`, and `IconURL` defined right above it.